# replace of chars that appear several times

Tags: php, string, str-replace

following:

I have a string which contains many spaces. I want to add a HTML Break "< br />"  in the next space-char after every 70 characters of this string for layout reasons. this is how far i'm in php:

```
function news_break( $news_string ){
    for( $i = 0; $i <= strlen($news_string); $i++ ){
        if( $i % 70 == 0 ){ //Every 70th char
            $c = TRUE;
        }
        if($c && $news_string[$i] == ' ' ){
            //?? replace space with <br />
            $c = FALSE; //Until the next 70th char is found
        }
    }
    return $news_string;
}
```

I know the first run will be 71 characters because of the $i = 0, but afterwards he will set $c = TRUE; after every 70 following chars. Not that important because he is supposed to look after a space_char afterwards, and the probability that it is exactly on 71 is pretty low

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
$wrapped = nl2br(wordwrap($news_string, 70));
```

instead?

Comment: this is not the op questioned! nl2br will convert \n \r\n to <br> and no whitespaces

Comment: uh, that's why there's `wordwrap` in there, which splits the string ever X chars and puts in a `\n`, which the nl2br then converts to a `<br>`, which is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: wordwarp was the thing i was looking for, thanks for the reply though

Comment: $news_string = wordwrap($news_string,70,"<br />"); is the deal

Answer (score 0):

you have to fill the replacement ... of course give a "parsed" string back

```
function news_break( $news_string ){
  $out = '';
  $c = false;
  for( $i = 0; $i <= strlen($news_string); $i++ ){
    if($i % 70 !=0 && $c===false)
       $out.=$news_string[$i];
    elseif( $i % 70 == 0 && $news_string[$i]!='' ){ //Every 70th char
        $c = true;
        $out.=$news_string[$i];
    } elseif ( $i % 70 == 0 && $news_string[$i]=='') 
        $out.=$news_string[$i].'<br>';
    elseif( $c=== true && $news_string[$i]=='') {
        $out.=$news_string[$i].'<br>';
        $c=false;
    } 
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Out of the box ... not tryed for errors ...